# Ionic Item Sliding ngIf Issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-list` that displays trip details. For the trip's status, there is an `ion-item-sliding` element that allows the user to do some action based on the status.

The issue is that when the action is performed and the status updates, the `*ngIf` that is being leveraged to show/hide the action appears to be effecting the sliding behavior.

For example, I have the following example where if the status is booked then the user can slide, click on "pickup", and the status is changed to `in_progress`. The issue is that the sliding behavior makes it so that the "complete" option is expanded and if you manually close it (either programmatically or if the user closes it) then it cannot be reopened:

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-divider color="primary">
    <ion-label>Trip 1</ion-label>
  </ion-item-divider>
  <ion-item-sliding #itemSlidingStatus>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Status:</ion-label> {{status}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end" *ngIf="status === 'booked'">
      <ion-item-option (click)="pickup()">Pickup</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item-options side="end" *ngIf="status === 'in_progress'">
      <ion-item-option (click)="complete()">Complete</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonItemSliding } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('itemSlidingStatus') private itemSlidingStatus: IonItemSliding;

  status = 'booked';

  complete(): void {
    this.status = 'completed';
  }

  pickup(): void {
    this.status = 'in_progress';
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jegkyc

How can I make it so that when I close the sliding option by calling `itemSlidingStatus.close()`, the element can be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your `ion-item-option` to single `ion-item-options`:

```
<ion-item-options side="end">
    <ion-item-option *ngIf="status === 'booked'" (click)="pickup()">
        Pickup
    </ion-item-option>

    <ion-item-option *ngIf="status === 'in_progress'" (click)="complete()">
        Complete
    </ion-item-option>
</ion-item-options>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the underlying issue, the bug still remains.

Comment: @David Is it not working for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhf3lu?file=src/app/app.component.html ?

Comment: Your stackblitz example is doing exactly what I described.

Comment: @David Really? Please, check it one more time. In your example, you can't open sliding options if you change status (to `in_progress`) and close an item. But in mine, you can do that.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure if there was a caching issue or what, but closing my browser and reopening the stackblitz example seemed to do the trick. It's working as expected now, thank you.